# What is the difference between push, grow, and fill in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

I see that `grow` and `push` accept an optional weighting parameter, but apart from that: what is the real difference between `grow`, `fill`, and `push`? The documentation isn't very clear about that.

Answer (score 5):

`push` affects only gaps, not elements, as far as I know.
If a component is set to `fill`, this means to set all *subcomponents* to `grow`, while `grow` affects the component directly.

Answer (score 1):

The `push` constraint does affect elements. It is only one of its contexts where
it makes gaps greedy.

The answer is a bit more complex. I have provided it in a more recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010068/miglayout-push-vs-grow/25014713#25014713).