# Sort the JTable with a dynamic growing data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am try to let a `JTable` always order, this table is void primary.

I add row by table model. How can I let the new adding row locate the order position?

```
//the add code
Object[] row= {current_hard_bin_degree,1,String.format("%.2f",1*100.0f/total_bins)+"%"};
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel();
model.addRow(te);
```

```
//i tried to this,but it just can be order when i click the header
 TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter
                 = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(myTable.getModel());
         myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
         sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
               try {
                  int a = Integer.parseInt(arg0.toString());
                  int b = Integer.parseInt(arg1.toString());
                  return a - b;
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                  return 0;
               }
            }
         });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuGg8.png)

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the table. Note that code which can be compiled and run is better than images of the tables. That's why I did not add the image in the edit. It adds no new information that wasn't already obvious from your description.

Comment: Why are you creating a custom Comparator. Just add a Double object to the TableModel and override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the model to return Double for that column and the table will use the appropriate comparator. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Fileter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

How about using growx? [MigLayout push VS grow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010068/miglayout-push-vs-grow)

for example,

```
private void display(int i) {
         model.add(sorter, "cell 0"+i+", growx");
}
```